# AWS: No Messages Available When Sending Message to SQS Queue from Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-lambda

What are some possible reasons why the following is not working for me?

1. Create a DynamoDB table `card_auth_events` with at least an `id` field.
2. Create a trigger that calls a lambda. Here is the lambda:

```
 console.log('Loading publishCardAuthEvent...');

 var QUEUE_URL = 'https://sqs.us-west2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/CardAuthEvents';
 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region : 'us-west-2'});
 var http = require('https');

 exports.handler = function(event, context) {
 event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
      console.log(record.eventID);
      console.log(record.eventName);
      console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
      sendToQueue(record);
 });
 context.succeed("Successfully processed " + event.Records.length + " records.");
};

function sendToQueue(message){
//Send SQS message with details of file uploaded to S3.
var params = {
  MessageBody: JSON.stringify(event),
  QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL
};

sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
  if (err) {
    console.log('error:',"Fail Send Message" + err);
    context.done('error', "ERROR Put SQS");  // ERROR with message

    } else {
      console.log('data:',data.MessageId);
      context.done(null,'');  // SUCCESS
    }
  });
}
```

3. Configure the Lambda to have a role with `AmazonSQSFullAccess`, `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`, and `AmazonAppStreamFullAccess`.
4. Create the Queue in SQS
5. Insert a record into the table.

**The trigger is getting called, but why is the message not put in the Queue???**

There are no messages in the queue and no errors in Cloud Watch. Is there some secret I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling your `sendToQueue()` function, and then calling `context.succeed()` without waiting for the resulting SQS API call to complete. This is terminating your Lambda function before it is finished.

Once you get past that, another problem is that you are calling `context.done()` inside the SQS callback, but you are potentially calling `sendToQueue()` multiple times. As soon as the first SQS API call returns your Lambda function is going to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your access policy. If you are using IAMFullAccess all you have done is given your lambda permission to access and change IAM policies, groups, users, etc. You need to give your lambda access to SQS. If you want to fully test lambda I suggest using the managed policy: `AWSLambdaFullAccess` and `AmazonSQSFullAccess`. That will open up S3, Lambda, DynamoDb, SQS and Cloudwatch.

Comment: I also have `AWSLambdaFullAccess` As well as other SQS Roles and it is still not working. I'll update the question.

Comment: Have you been able to insert anything into the queue yet? For instance, running an insert from the CLI or running your script locally? And do you have any output from the lambda running?

Comment: I can add a message to the queue directly from the SQS console

Comment: Get it to work from code first. Don't try to jump straight into using Lambda with untested code. You are just giving yourself a headache.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll see if I can add a message to queue using Apache Camel